# ASP.NET MVC Web.config maxRequestLength seems to be ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm trying to change the maximum upload file size on my local IIS server for a ASP.NET MVC app. I am using IE 11 to run the app.

Ultimately, I will want the maximum upload file size to apply just to certain pages. For now, though, I'm just trying to get it to work across the site and it appears that the values I'm trying to set are being ignored.

In Webconfig.cs, I put this within the  section:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" maxRequestLength="100000" />
</system.web>
```

When I check the value of the max request length in the controller, I am still getting 4 MB (the IIS default):

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection section = config.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime") as System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection;
double maxFileSize = Math.Round(section.MaxRequestLength / 1024.0, 1);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you have added the maxRequestLength to the applications web.config file and not the web.config file within the View folder.